# Tricky trigonometry - the starting position of a wave in a predefined mesh in matlab

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

I am modelling the propagation of a planar acoustic using Matlab. I'm trying to write a loop which varies the angle of incidence of the wave and then runs the simulation. Quite simple, but I'm struggling to define the acoustic wave within the loop. It's quite simple to illustrate, but essentially encoding the trig problem is causing me trouble.

[image: image of scenario]

I've done this for the case of a point source as follows

```
angular_increments = 300;
for i=1:angular_increments,
    % source position is positive along the  y-z-axis
    theta= 0+(angular_inc *i);
    x_position = 0; % fixed - independant of angle
    y_position = d * cos((pi/2)-theta);
    y_position = y_position * dy;
    z_position = d * sin((pi/2)-theta);
    z_position = z_position * dz;

    % Source function - defines a point of pressure
    source_grid = (kgrid.x = x_position);
    source_grid = source_grid&(kgrid.y = y_position);
    source_grid = source_grid&(kgrid.z = z_position);
```

Any ideas on how to approach this would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try applying the [Huygens principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle): You solve the problem for several individual rays, where you calculate ray propagation at different time points. Then, you combine the position of the individual rays at every given time point to form your wavefront, either by fitting a straight line through the points, or by applying a spline (in case the interface between wave and medium is more complex, or the medium is inhomogeneous.